# How to Convert JsonValue to JSONObject

Tags: json

I m using Jaql to manipulate data(data stored in json converted to string). The output for Jaql will be a com.ibm.jaql.json.type.JsonValue. It can be stored into string through toString() method. I got to do some json manipulations on the returned value. Problem here is, the output is not actual simple JSONObject. Is there a way to transform my string or JsonValue to JSONObject???

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `String` constructor of `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - Nicolas

Comment: You can validate the answer.

Comment: I m using JsonSimpleParser. It has constructor only to access Map.